# pimpl desgin pattern , member functions need to be put in private class

Tags: c++, design-patterns, pimpl-idiom

to ensure the ABI with the pimpl pattern, is that true that we only need to put all the data members to the "Private class" ?  I see in some introduction about pimpl, they also make all the functions implementations in the "Private class" and define a "wrapper function" on the exported class for each function in the "Private class", is that necessary?

Comment: I assume the previous ABI already is using pimpl so you already have a pointer for your private implementation.

Answer (score 2):

When your aim is to have ABI compatibility, then you need to put all data member variables in the private class.

There is [this famous article about c++ ABI compatibility](https://community.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C%2B%2B). From their to do's/don'ts :

- you can not change the signature of existing member functions. You can add new methods
- you can not add virtual functions to a class without one
- you can not add or change non-static data members, or change their order

The list goes on, but these 3 items should cover your questions.

As long as you are 100% sure you are not going to modify private member functions, it is fine. If you expect a change, move them to a private class. I always expect a change.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of wrapping the functions is that then the functions can be defined in the "private" aka "implementation" class. (Although I always use a struct. Since the entire thing is private to one file I don't see the point to protecting its implementation.)

Since the functions are defined in the same class as the data, you don't need to stick `p->` on the front of every access like `p->variable`.

If you put data in the implementation class/struct but no functions, then all of your function definitions need to put that `p->` before every access.